# Scrolling Popup Window Out of Screen

Tags: javascript, popup, window

We open popup window. We want to slide this off the screen. The "Right" and "Top" parts can be made as much as possible. How can we slide out of the screen?

```
var wind = window.open("https://www.google.com","","width=50,height=50,left=1500%,top=1000%");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not exactly sure about your particular use case, but by toggling opacity and right/left, you can achieve the "effect" of the div going out of the screen.

```js
function move() {
  let element = document.getElementById("box");
  element.style.transform = "translate(-400px)";
  element.style.right = 0;
  element.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Hello</div>

<button id="btn" onclick="move()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. We open Popup window with Javascript. We want this pop-up window to go off screen. We want the window I show in the picture I added to be invisible or to exit the screen. How can we do it?

We open the window like this. "var wind = window.open (" http://google.com "," "," width = 50, height = 50, left = 1500%, top = 1000% ");